# When making an interactive fiction game in javascript and HTML, should I make one big file or multiple smaller ones?

Tags: javascript, html, game-development

Making an account here since I'm relatively new to programming. I'm currently making an interactive fiction game with javascript and HTML just as an exploration of how to do things with the languages (I know it's ambitious for a beginner, but I'm not asking for help with that part.)

My current question here is essentially just the title. I currently have everything in one .html file, which is getting larger as I go. Superficial googling tells me that having one file at the time is good for the end user but doesn't matter otherwise, but I'll be compiling it with Electron once I'm done so I wasn't sure if that would effect anything.

I know how to do it, I'm just not sure if I should, and what the pros/cons would be either way.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Tools like webpack let you work with different files so your code can be organized. Webpack can compile your whole project to a single file later and dont worry for performance issues

Comment: Welcome to SO. Almost nothing of any complexity ships as a single file, unless it is run through a compiler which joins your various component scripts and files into one output file. If you're new, work with multiple files either through a framework like VUE or JavaScript modules.